# Get and display lat long from address using Leaflet Control Search

Tags: javascript, leaflet, google-geocoder

I am using leaflet.js and this plugin: https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search and need a way of getting the lat and long coordinates from the address search and putting them into an input field, or just being able to use them...

The answer may well be in the code below, just can't figure out how to do it...

```
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

                function googleGeocoding(text, callResponse)
                {
                    geocoder.geocode({address: text}, callResponse);
                }

                function filterJSONCall(rawjson)
                {
                    var json = {},
                        key, loc, disp = [];

                    for(var i in rawjson)
                    {
                        key = rawjson[i].formatted_address;

                        loc = L.latLng( rawjson[i].geometry.location.lat(), rawjson[i].geometry.location.lng() );

                        json[ key ]= loc;   //key,value format
                    }

                    return json;
                }

                map.addControl( new L.Control.Search({
                        callData: googleGeocoding,
                        filterJSON: filterJSONCall,
                        wrapper: 'findbox',
                        markerLocation: true,
                        autoType: false,
                        autoCollapse: true,
                        minLength: 5,
                        zoom: 10,
                        initial: true,
                        collapsed: false,
                        tipAutoSubmit: false,
                        autoResize: false,
                        text: 'Enter an Address'
                    }) );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the leaflet-search.js file you have a function called

> _getLocation(this._input.value)

This function returns the information you need. You can see it's called inside the _handleSubmit function like this:

```
var loc = this._getLocation(this._input.value);
```

If you do:

```
console.log("Latitude: " + loc.lat);
console.log("Longitude: " + loc.lng);
```

bellow this call in leaflet-search.js you will get the info you need in the console.

I gave you the info you needed, now it's up to you to use it how you like. Make a public function then access it inside your code or whatever you want.

Comment: This is great, thank you. I got it to write the value to the console and also to an input field, but there is one problem... it's writing a string like this: LatLng(42.70002, -91.86391), instead I need just the latlong  - like this: 42.70002, -91.86391. Any ideas how I would reformat the output?

Comment: I've edited my answer, now you can read lat (latitude) and lng (longitude) explicitly.

Comment: okay so to combine them into the format I need I would do this:  console.log(loc.lat,loc.lng); ?

Comment: Okay I got it: `var longi = loc.lng;
  var lati = loc.lat;
  var location = longi + "," + lati;
  $("#latlongit").val(location);`

Answer (score -1):

```
 var searchbox =  new L.Control.Search({
                            callData: googleGeocoding,
                            filterJSON: filterJSONCall,
                            wrapper: 'findbox',
                            markerLocation: true,
                            autoType: false,
                            autoCollapse: true,
                            minLength: 5,
                            zoom: 10,
                            initial: true,
                            collapsed: false,
                            tipAutoSubmit: false,
                            autoResize: false,
                            text: 'Enter an Address'
                        });

    searchbox.on('search_locationfound', function(e) {
                var locLat = e.latlng.lat;
                var locLng = e.latlng.lng;
                console.log(locLat+', '+locLng);
            });
```

This works fine with me. I hope I might help other people with this. :)