# How to get lat/long of the searched position with leaflet search?

Tags: leaflet

I'm using leaflet search to localize me without any automatic localization methods. I need to work with lat, long of the found place after click on some filter.

I have read this and tried to use it:
[Get and display lat long from address using Leaflet Control Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31280978/get-and-display-lat-long-from-address-using-leaflet-control-search)

My call in a onchange function of the filter:

```
var loc = searchControl._getLocation(this._input.value);
console.log("Latitude: " + loc.lat);
console.log("Longitude: " + loc.lng);
```

But got this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`

I guess I call the `_getLocation` function late, the searchControl is cleared, right? So when/how could I get the lat long data from it? Is there som event handler for "searched place was found"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe like this?

```js
searchControl.on('search:locationfound', function(e) {
    var locLat = e.latlng.lat;
    var locLng = e.latlng.lng;
    console.log(locLat+', '+locLng);
});
```

I assume the `_getLocation()` method is async, e.g. your `console.log()` statements try to read values before they exist.

but if I look at the [code](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search/blob/master/dist/leaflet-search.src.js#L856) I doubt this will work by calling `_getLocation()` directly as the event is fired within `_handleSubmit()` which itself calls the `_getLocation()` method and then fires that event...

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed.